# does Excel VBA interpret the character ChrW(&H1D48) as a superscript d?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently upgraded from Excel for Mac 2011 to Excel for Mac 2016 and discovered a bug.  I want to find out if this problem is specific to VBA Excel for Mac 2016 or if it is happening with other computers.

```
Dim gg As Range
Set gg = Range("a1:s16000")
gg.Replace What:=ChrW(&H1D48), Replacement:="|d", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

This code will correctly change `heyᵈ` into `hey|d`.  But it will incorrectly change `dude` into `|du|de` and that's not supposed to happen because `ChrW(&H1D48)` is not normal d but superscript d.  I did not have this problem with Excel for Mac 2011 but only Excel for Mac 2016 and would like to know if others are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: It should interpret it that way (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHiOC.png)), it just cannot display it as such.

Comment: No, I'm trying to make sure that VBA does not mistake d for ChrW(&H1D48).  They're not the same character and right now VBA is mistaking d for ChrW(&H1D48).

Comment: Excel's probably trying to help you out, in the same way it defaults to `D`=`d`.  Try using `MatchCase := True`

Comment: @ashleedawg - that seems to be the best answer. I got hung up on binary compares and strconv's.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped... you motivated me to rephrase as an answer; Feel free to throw others my way.. (That last lil' bit o' rep I need for 10K is taking for-*everr!*)  :-)

Comment: Small potatoes; my problem is 10× that. Of course, answering in comments doesn't do much to alleviate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's trying to help you out by being case-insensitive.

While the English Alphabet may only have pairs of matching characters (ie, `D` vs `d`), characters exist that may be considered equivalent in other languages for characters sets.

In the *case* of your character: `d = D = ᵈ = ⅆ`

A more common example (where I live, anyway) would be `E = e = É = é`.

You should be able to avoid this issue by making your search case-insensitive by changing `MatchCase := True`.

Also see [this information](https://support.office.com/article/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-sensitive-7f302a1e-5a3b-421c-b00a-615c89bc39ba) about the `EXACT` function for comparing strings.

---

## `Option Compare`

Another *option* is to declare your sensitivity at the module level, with the `Option Compare` statement:

*Syntax:*
**`Option Compare {`** *`Binary|Text|Database`* **`}`**

If used, the `Option Compare` statement must appear in a module before any procedures. The `Option Compare` statement specifies the **string comparison method** (`Binary`, `Text`, or `Database`) for a module. If a module doesn't include an `Option Compare` statement, the **default** text comparison method is `**Binary**`.

- **`Option Compare Binary`** results in string comparisons based on a sort order derived from the internal binary representations of the characters. In Microsoft Windows, sort order is determined by the code page. A typical binary sort order is shown in the following example:

  > ```
  > A < B < E < Z < a < b < e < z < À < Ê < Ø < à < ê < ø
  > ```
- **`Option Compare Text`** results in string comparisons based on a case-insensitive text sort order determined by your system's locale. When the same characters are sorted using `Option Compare Text`, the following text sort order is produced:

  > ```
  > (A=a) < ( À=à) < (B=b) < (E=e) < (Ê=ê) < (Z=z) < (Ø=ø)
  > ```

---

(See the [**source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-compare-statement) for more information.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but both those solutions did not work.

Comment: Is it possible to put the Exact function into VBA? I tried `gg.Replace What:=ChrW(&H1D48), Replacement:="|d", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, Exact:=True` but that did not work.

Comment: Almost any worksheet function can be called using VBA with [`Application.WorksheetFunction` functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-object-excel)... but apparently `Exact` is one of the few you can't. However, you can do without it. See this post on [**Mr. Excel**](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/355333-worksheet-function-exact-post1756338.html#post1756338).

Comment: So would what he is talking about here solve my problem "If, however, you are using the Option Compare Text, you can use the vba function StrComp() with the Compare argument equal to vbBinaryCompare."